# .netcore Sqlite can't create database

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core

It is simple and silly.

This is the code:

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("" +
                new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    DataSource = "hello.db"
                }))
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
        }
```

It does not work.  It can't be simpler, but it still doesn't work.  The Internet seems quiet about that problem.

It throws an exception on Open();  Exception is this:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.NullReferenceException An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll: 'Object reference not set to an instance of
>   an object.'    at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()    at
>   archive.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   D:\projects\test\Program.cs:line 55

What is going on?

Please note - I am working on a piece of code that was using System.Data.Sqlite and old, 'normal' .net

When I moved to Microsoft.Data.Sqlite (and .net core), it protests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlLite` NuGet package for this to work, if you don't and you only have reference to `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` you will get this error.